# PHP Sorting Arrays Logically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array in PHP so it sorts numbers as part of a string logically....I have strings like:

1M, 15M, 1.5M, 3M, 38M 3.5M

Which I want sorted numerically like

1M, 1.5M 3M, 3.5M, 38M

It seems there should be an easy way to do this, but I can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do this.

```
$arr = array('1M', '15M', '1.5M', '3M', '38M', '3.5M');
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
   $a1 = str_replace("M", "", $a);
   $b1 = str_replace("M", "", $b);
   return $a1 > $b1;
});
var_dump($arr);
```

This returns;

```
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  string(2) "1M"
  [1] =>
  string(4) "1.5M"
  [2] =>
  string(2) "3M"
  [3] =>
  string(4) "3.5M"
  [4] =>
  string(3) "15M"
  [5] =>
  string(3) "38M"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function sort_array($array){
    $newArr = array();
    foreach($array as $value){
        $newArr[] = floatval(explode("M", $value)[0]);
    }
    sort($newArr);
    foreach($newArr as $key => $value){
        $newArr[$key] = $value . "M";
    }
    return $newArr;
}

$array = array("1M", "15M", "1.5M", "3M", "38M", "3.5M");
$sorted_array = sort_array($array);
print_r($sorted_array); // Array ( [0] => 1M [1] => 1.5M [2] => 3M [3] => 3.5M [4] => 15M [5] => 38M )
```

Comment: You could use `rtrim` for instead of `explode`. But it useless anyway. Floatval works well in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to sort out your problem :

```
function cmp($a, $b){       
    return (floatval($a) == floatval($b)?0:((floatval($a) < floatval($b)) ? -1 : 1));
}

$a = array("1M", "15M", "1.5M", "3M", "38M","3.5M");

usort($a, "cmp");
print_r($a);
// foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    // echo "$key: $value\n";
// }

Output : Array ( [0] => 1M [1] => 1.5M [2] => 3M [3] => 3.5M [4] => 15M [5] => 38M )
```

May be this help you out. :D

Comment: Why don't just `return floatval($a)- floatval($b)`? Or spaceship for PHP7. : )

Comment: it's all up to you bro @sectus... :)

I just gave a clue to solve that problem. Anything improvement, it's all up to the programmer it self. hehe :D

Answer (score -1):

My best bet is to use [floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) to convert your mixed string to a float.

Comment: Sorry. I can explain all the steps you need to do if necessary. Have you tried just calling .sort() on your array?
Otherwise, loop over your array and use floatval on all items. Then use .sort(), and finally append 'M' if you need it to be there on your values. You would need to loop over your array again if that's the case.